# Is the problem "find the sequence of $N$ numbers between 1 and $D$ with least cost", NP-hard?

Tags: optimization, reductions, np-hard, combinatorics

Consider sequences $p=(p_1,\dots,p_N)$ (the order matters) of length $N$, where $p_i\in\{1,\dots,D\}$ for fixed $D$. Moreover, consider a cost function $c:\{1,\dots,D\}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ which comply $c(q)\neq c(p), \forall p,q\in\{1,\dots,D\}^N$ with $p\neq q$. The problem is to find $p\in\{1,\dots,D\}^N$ with least cost $c(p)$. **I want to show that this problem is NP-hard**.

In my opinion, since all costs are different, there is no other way but to check all possible ($D^N$) combinations to find the optimum. Should this be enough to conclude that this problem is NP-hard? If so, what is the "formal argument" under this line of reasoning?

Alternatively, is there a standard reference which state that a problem like this is NP-hard? Which other NP-hard problem can be reduced to this one?

Comment: How is the input encoded? If you have no assumptions on $c$, then $c$ needs to be passed explicitly as input, which means that the problem is trivially in $P$. Also, for $N\ge 1$ and $D \ge 1$, no function can possibly satisfy $c(q) \neq c(p) \; \forall p,q \in \{1, \dots, D\}^N$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why no function can satisfy that? I think of $c$ as a table which maps a combination $p$ to a real number. I don't see any problem in letting all these numbers to be different. I'm not sure I understand the "trivially in $P$" part. Thanks

Comment: If $D \ge 1$ and $N \ge 1$ then $\{1, \dots, D\}^N \neq \emptyset$ and a valid choice for $p$ and $q$ is $p = q = (1, 1, \dots, 1)$. Then $c(p) = c(q)$ violating the condition $c(p) \neq q \; \forall \{1, \dots, D\}^N$.
If $c$ is given explicitly, then the input size is at least $\Omega(D^N)$, so you can explicitly check all possible combinations.

Comment: Oh! I thought I wrote $p\neq q$ in the problem. My apologies, I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I see, so to show NP-hard, the argument would follow by checking that the input size of the order of $D^N$? Or since its the input that its already of exponential size, then the problem is P in the input size $D^N$? I may be mixing concepts..

Comment: If $P \neq NP$ and $c$ is given explicitly the problem cannot be NP-hard since it can be solved in time $O(\mathrm{poly}\, n)$, where $n$ is the input size.

Comment: Is there other name/terminology I can use for this problem to empathize how hard it is then?

Comment: You can just say that solving this problem requires exponential time in $N$.

Comment: I see. That's what I wanted to say, my only problem was that "requires" part. One solution is to look into all possible combinations and this time grows exponentially with $N$, yes. But I wanted to empathize that this is probably the only thing you can do.

Comment: What one can do is strongly related what the assumptions on $c$ are and to how $c$ is encoded. If you know nothing more than what you said in your question then you need to explicitly test all the $\Omega(D^N)$ possible vectors $p$, which makes the problem not really interesting...

Comment: Ok, I think I have a more clear idea of what I want then. Thanks sir.

Comment: NP-hardness is a category of *decision problems*, that is, problems where the answer is either Yes or No. What decision problem are you interested in?

Comment: So, I'm reading "Combinatorial optimization" by Korte, and there it says that "A computational problem X is called NP-hard if all problems in NP polynomially reduce to X". And apparently these "computational problem" include optimization problems, and not only decision problems. Do you think this is not the standard definition then? Maybe I should read a different book.